# I want count up time when browser open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first Chrome extension which starts a timer when the browser is launched.
For example: 00:00:00 --> 00:00:01 --> 00:00:02
I have pasted my code below. Is this the best option for doing this?

```
$(function () {
    startCount();
});

function startCount() {
    timer = setInterval(count, 1000);
}

function count() {
    var time_shown = $("#realtime").text();
    var time_chunks = time_shown.split(":");
    var hour, mins, secs;
    hour = Number(time_chunks[0]);
    mins = Number(time_chunks[1]);
    secs = Number(time_chunks[2]);
    secs++;

    if (secs == 60) {
        secs = 0;
        mins = mins + 1;
    }

    if (mins == 60) {
        mins = 0;
        hour = hour + 1;
    }

    if (hour == 13) {
        hour = 0;
    }

    $("#realtime").text(timezero(hour) + ":" + timezero(mins) + ":" + timezero(secs));
}

function timezero(digit) {
    var str = digit + '';

    if (digit < 10) {
        str = "0" + str;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

That code will not work for many reasons. For example it assumes that it will never miss a second but it will miss some (see the docs on timeout/intervals. It also overcomplicates the calculation. Just remember Date.now() on load and use the interval to recalculate the difference with the new now()

Comment: I'd like to ask you, which question are you answering?

Comment: Ok i see your point. Yes i think its not well phrased and im not sure if he even meant to ask about how to calculate the difference or how/where to display it.

Comment: We need to make a user do at least minimal work before answering. It just encourages bad questions if we answer anyway, guessing half of the question. He's a new user; fine, give benefit of doubt and guide with comments if you want, that would be good.

Comment: I usually follow that rule thou this time i do see code and effort and that code wasnt copied from somewhere else so i adventured an answer

Comment: I agree, but we need to know which part to fix. "Is this the best way to do it?" The answer to that is "No", not "No, that's better: ...", because we don't know what the user is unhappy with.